# Blender flickering faces in viewport

Tags: mesh

I have a problem with flickering faces for months now.

I made a video to show the problem better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1uMXez6ruI

I start with a new project with the standard cube, copy it 4 times, and when i go to edit mode of 1 cube, the other three cubes start to flicker. (you can clearly see the problem at 00:19)
I hope someone can point me in the right direction for solving this!

What i have tried up until now:
I made sure it is not z-fighting, uninstalled and reinstalled newest blender version, Clip start is at 0.01m so should be good.
Also turning of AA did not fixed it.
This were the most common solutions I found on the internet and did not worked.

Comment: I can't see any trace of that effect here. Have you checked that you have the latest graphics drivers installed?

Comment: Hi man, I don't know if you know but this issue was already resolved in that thread that I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

yes this is Radeon 6000 series issue, it is already known and a lot of people have this issue, it is just because of drivers not being 100% compatible with blender... unfortunately I have 6700XT as well and I wrote the same question here as well (there is also thread at blender community with this as a bug so don't worry they know about it...
You can find more about it here:

https://developer.blender.org/T87927 (this is a thread related to this issue)

It occurs in edit mode, weight paint and some previews

We may just hope that Blender 3.0.0 and new drivers in December will solve this

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just found the solution somewhere else, under 'viewport overlays' deselect the 'fade inactive geometry' and no more flickering now!

Edit: It is likely a videocard issue, I have an AMD radeon RX 6700XT with the latest drivers.

Comment: I have that option checked but it seems to be set to 0.4 by default here.